# Was Ambassador Christopher Stevens raped before his death?

Tags: united-states, politics

US Ambassador to Libya, [Christopher Stevens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Stevens_%28ambassador%29) was killed in one of the recent [attacks against the US Diplomatic Missions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_U.S._diplomatic_missions_attacks).

[NOPCRadio claim](http://www.nopcradio.com/nopc-news/news/67-ambassador-stevens-was-raped-before-he-was-killed.html) that he was raped before his death.  Here is a report that claims the same from [Lebonon News](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://www.tayyar.org/Tayyar/News/PoliticalNews/ar-LB/usa-killed-lybia-zek-970.htm) (via google translate).

Is this true?

Note: Actually I just realized that the comment comes from a very anti islamic site and hence biased. However, it's being spread on facebook and most people that read it believe it. Currently I do not think it's true. However, politically incorrect facts is often hidden and I am still not sure.

The report comes from Lebanese media.
http://www.tayyar.org/Tayyar/News/PoliticalNews/ar-LB/usa-killed-lybia-zek-970.htm

Use google or some other translator to read it.

Comment: Downvote again? What did I do now? This question is mysogynist? C'mon.

Comment: I don't think the claim is from notable source.

Comment: I suspect the downvote was because the question was poorly worded, insensitive, and had some unnecessary speculations. I have tried to correct that; I fear it remains insensitive, due to the nature of the claim.

Comment: Actually I just realized that the comment comes from a very anti islamic site. However, it's being spread on facebook and most people that read it believe it. Again thanks Oddthinking.

Comment: btw. I've retracted the downvote after the question is reedited, but I still don't think it's notable source.

Comment: I'm surprised it took very long to realise it was an anti-Islamic site, when the first sentence refers to Muslims as "scum".

Comment: I contest that most people believe what they read on face book... if you do I have news for you... cats and dogs can not really type and are not thinking that.  Second this question has no value.  Worse than being raped he was murdered.  Whether or not he was raped is not really relevant to anyone here, or to many elsewhere for that matter.  My down vote is fore that reason.

Comment: Now that there is a more reliable source I have removed my downvote.  Though I still say there is nothing to be learned of value in the answer to this question.

Comment: @Chad That is a terrible reason to down vote a question.  You don't need any more reason to question a dubious claim than the pursuit of truth in every thing that we do.

Comment: @maple_shaft - You did not read the comments actually.  There was no claim it was just a question with no notable claim.  I still find no value in the question but having a notable claim at least brings it into the realm of ontopic so the downvote was removed...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No**

> The Libyan doctor who treated Mr Stevens in hospital said **he had died
>   of severe asphyxiation, apparently from smoke inhalation, with no
>   other injuries**, and that he had tried for 90 minutes to revive him.
>
> He was the only American brought into the Benghazi Medical Centre and
>   initially nobody realised he was the ambassador, Ziad Abu Zeid told
>   the Associated Press news agency.

source: [BBC News](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-19570254)

Comment: Not being a doctor, is 90 minutes of trying to revive someone normal? Sounds awfully long to me.

Comment: @picakhu: "revive" isn't strictly medical term as "resuscitate". Former might mean that during some of that time he was unconscious but breathing.

Comment: No I do not accept the word of the Lybian doctor the government put forward to forestall a war with the US.  I do not blame Libya for doing it and unlike much of the country that will vote similar to me I do not think we should go to war with Libya.  But neither do I take that doctor as a credible source of information.

Comment: @Chad: you're suggesting, that whenever an embassy is attacked and diplomats killed, US goes to war with the host country? Is US at war with Nigeria and Tanzania? Or has China declared war on US, after USAF bombed it's embassy?

Comment: @Chad: well, while back US senator wanted to send SEALs to Iceland, when they didn't want to hand over Assange. So I'd take what politicians say with a grain of salt.

Comment: I can not believe that this is being up voted....

Comment: @Chad: YPB? BBC is very reliable source.

Comment: @Vartec - I believe the Lybian government got a doctor to say that yes.  I do not find the doctor credible.